# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined after applying Bootstrap Template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I am working on a MVC project. I downloaded a bootstrap theme called argon and tried to integrate with MVC. I referenced all the Argon related css and javascript files in Bundle.Config. 
    I think it got integrated successfully as well as i can use all the argon html elements now.
    Problem is i am not able to use jquery functions properly. I added jquery reference at the top of all other plugins . But always getting this error - 
    "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".
    I searched and I know it is pretty common problem but did not find a suitable solution for this.
    Not sure where I am making the mistake.

```
Any suggestion would be helpful. TIA.


This is what I have tried - 

Bundle Config File :

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Argon/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js",
                        "~/Argon/assets/js/argon.min.js",
                        "~/Argon/assets/vendor/popper/popper.min.js",
                        "~/Argon/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js",
                        "~/Argon/assets/vendor/headroom/headroom.min.js",
                        "~/Argon/assets/vendor/onscreen/onscreen.min.js",
                        "~/Argon/assets/vendor/nouislider/js/nouislider.min.js",
                        "~/Argon/assets/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"
                        ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/argon/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/argon/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/argon").Include(
                "~/Argon/assets/css/argon.min.css",
                "~/Argon/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-grid.min.css",
                "~/Argon/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-reboot.min.css",
                "~/Argon/assets/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css",
                "~/Argon/assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
                "~/Argon/assets/vendor/nouislider/css/nouislider.min.css",
                "~/Argon/assets/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo-svg.css",
                "~/Argon/assets/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css"
                ));



THE LAYOUT PAGE:


    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/argon")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")*@
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>



THE INDEX PAGE:

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-calendar-grid-58"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control datepicker" id="dtTime" placeholder="Select date" type="text"/> 
            <button type="button" id="btnDate" class="btn btn-outline-default">Default</button>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnDate").on('click', function (e) {
           var dtval = $('.datepicker').val();
           console.log(dtval);
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Don't need round of applause for this but add:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before your `<script>` tag or in `<head></head>`

Comment: Yes.. right you are... Works like a charm now... Thanks!

Comment: Apologies... Didn't know I can not mark two answers as accepted..you are the first one to answer..

Answer (score 1):

if you have a master page example:

> _Layout.chtml

you have to put the code into each page that you are going to render

```
@section Scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready!");

            $("#Pdf").click(function () {
                alert("pdf button");
                window.open('../Home/PrintStudent?param=1', '_blank');
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` is because of `jQuery` js is missing while loading the page. if you have a master page example: `_Layout.chtml`, add the following js file inside `<body>` and hence it will be available for every page with this layout.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @JK1990 happy to help, don't forget to mark the response as accepted to make it clear to future visitors ;)

Comment: Plagiarism at its finest!